# Is there a way to detect in r if two strings have some characters in common?

Tags: r, dataframe, join, tidyverse, fuzzyjoin

Reproducable example:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(stringr)

df1 <- data.frame(x = c("Victoria Park Ave N & Pachino Blvd, Toronto, ON",
                        "The West Mall S & The Queensway, Toronto, ON",
                        "Willowdale Ave NS & Athabaska Ave, Toronto, ON"), y = c(1:3))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c("Victoria Park Ave / Pachino Blvd",
                        "Athabaska Ave / Willowdale Ave", 
                        "The Queensway / The West Mall",
                        "Dundas/ Younge"
                        ), z = c(66:69))

fuzzyjoin <- df2 %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(., df1, by = "x",  match_fun = str_detect )
```

expected output

[image]

I appreciate any suggestion

Comment: This seems more of a "string distance" thing than if they share letters. Look at [`stringdist`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @r2evans .I tried with `stringdist_inner_join` and `max_dist = 2`, but somehow didn't work out.

Comment: I suggest you look at the raw distance between each of the strings before you stop using it, I suggest `mas_dist=2` is too low. For instance, the first string from each vector has a distance of 16 (`stringdist::stringdist("Victoria Park Ave N & Pachino Blvd, Toronto, ON", "Victoria Park Ave / Pachino Blvd")`).

Comment: For a complete look at the comparisons done with these two vectors, try `outer(df1$x, df2$x, stringdist::stringdist)` and see what the distances are; in this case, ranging from 16 to 43.